# Why CopyConstructible definition mention "rvalue expression of const T"?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, copy-constructor

Following is definition from cppreference:

[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible][1]

> Requirements: The type T satisfies CopyConstructible if
>
> The type T satisfies MoveConstructible, and Given
>
> v, an lvalue expression of type T or const T or an rvalue expression
>   of type const T u, an arbitrary identifier The following expressions
>   must be valid and have their specified effects
>
> Expression    Post-conditions T u = v;    The value of u is equivalent to
>   the value of v. The value of v is unchanged
>
> T(v)  The value of T(v) is equivalent to the value of v. The value of v
>   is unchanged.

My question is following line:

> v, an lvalue expression of type T or const T or an rvalue expression 
>   of type const T

I did not understand part of this "rvalue expression of type const T"? Why this "rvalue expression of type const T" is there in definition of CopyConstructible? Can someone please explain with example? The definition of MoveConstructible (which is pre-condition for CopyConstructible) already includes that requirement, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the definition of [*MoveConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible) only care about non-const rvalue expressions, because you can't move-from const.

*CopyConstructible* extends that to cover the remaining possibilities for `T u = v;` and `T(v);`.

Note that a copy-only type still satisfies *MoveConstructible* if it leaves `rv` unchanged, as that is covered by "The new value of `rv` is unspecified."

As an example

```
struct Foo {
    void Bar() { /* modify Foo somehow */ }
};

const Foo createFoo() { return {}; }

Foo foo = createFoo(); // Must copy, as the return value is const
```

This sort of construction occurs in pre-C++11 code, where the author wishes to forbid constructs like `createFoo().Bar();` because it is an error to modify a temporary `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks. It explained well.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example that produces error in C++11/14, since `X` is *MoveConstructible* but not *CopyConstructible*:

```
struct X {
   X() = default;
   X(const X&) = delete;
   X(X&&) = default;
};

const X f1() { return X{}; }
X f2() { return X{}; }

int main() {
   X x1 = f1(); // copy-initialization from const rvalue: ERROR
   X x2 = f2(); // copy-initialization from rvalue: OK
}
```

Note that in C++17 there is no error since only default constructor is invoked.